# clearing input fields changing slides and on button input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having multiple slides which will hold multiple forms. I want to clear out the radio input fields when I change the slide or do a submit. Seems to me my approach isnt working. Any suggestion?

here is the code I have so far

```
<style>
.yesDisplay, .noDisplay, .yesSub{
display:none;
}
.myc { display:none; }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {
    var $myc= $('.myc');
    var cp = 0;

    $('#pauseB').click (function () {

       $myc.hide().eq(cp++).show();       
       if (cp == $myc.length) cp = 0;  
    });

// check the radio input for Yes
function checkYes(){
    if($('.yes').attr('checked')){
            $('.yesDisplay').show();
        }else{
            $('.yesDisplay').hide();
        }
}
// check the radio input for No
function checkNo(){
    if($('.no').attr('checked')){
            $('yesDisplay').show();
        }else{
            $('.noDisplay').hide();
        }
}

    $('.cases').change(function(){
        checkYes();
        checkNo();
    });

});


</script>

<div id="pauseB">Pause</div> 
<div id="one" class="myc">1<br>
    <form class="cases">
        <input type="radio" class="yes" name="first"/>yes
        <input type="radio" class="no" name="first"/>no
    </form>
    <div class="display">
        <div class="yesDisplay">Secondary Question
            <form class="cases">
                <input type="radio" class="yes1" name="first"/>yes
                <input type="radio" class="no1" name="first"/>no
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="noDisplay"><input type="button" value="test"/></div>
        <div class="yesSub">1.1</div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div id="two" class="myc">2<br>
    <form class="cases">
        <input type="radio" class="yes" name="first"/>yes
        <input type="radio" class="no" name="first"/>no
    </form>
    <div class="display">
        <div class="yesDisplay">Secondary Question
            <form class="cases">
                <input type="radio" class="yes1" name="first"/>yes
                <input type="radio" class="no1" name="first"/>no
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="noDisplay">no</div>
        <div class="yesSub">1.1</div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div id="three" class="myc">3</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can unselect a radio button, my professor mentioned that in class a couple months ago.

Comment: well there is a way of doing that...something like $(':input').attr('checked', false);...but the question is how to apply it to all the other children of the sibling.